How Do I Get Python To Capture My Screen At The Right Frame Rate
I have this python script that is supposed to record my screen, on mac os.
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import subprocess
import time

def record_screen():
    # Define the screen resolution
    screen_width, screen_height = 1440, 900  # Adjust this to match your screen resolution
    fps = 30  # Target FPS for recording

    # Define the ffmpeg command
    ffmpeg_cmd = [
        'ffmpeg',
        '-y',  # Overwrite output file if it exists
        '-f', 'rawvideo',
        '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
        '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
        '-s', f'{screen_width}x{screen_height}',  # Size of one frame
        '-r', str(fps),  # Input frames per second
        '-i', '-',  # Input from pipe
        '-an',  # No audio
        '-vcodec', 'libx264',
        '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
        '-crf', '18',  # Higher quality
        '-preset', 'medium',  # Encoding speed
        'screen_recording.mp4'
    ]

    # Start the ffmpeg process
    ffmpeg_process = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    frame_count = 0
    start_time = time.time()

    while True:
        # Capture the screen
        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        img_np = np.array(img)

        # Convert and resize the frame
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        resized_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (screen_width, screen_height))

        # Write the frame to ffmpeg
        ffmpeg_process.stdin.write(resized_frame.tobytes())

        # Display the frame
        cv2.imshow('Screen Recording', resized_frame)

        # Stop recording when 'q' is pressed
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # Close the ffmpeg process
    ffmpeg_process.stdin.close()
    ffmpeg_process.wait()

    # Release everything when job is finished
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    record_screen()



As you can see, it should be 30 frames per second, but the problem is that when I open the file afterwards its all sped up. I think it has to do with the frame capture rate as oppose to the encoded rate. I'm not quite sure though. If I try to speed the video down afterwards so that it plays in real time the video is just really choppy. And the higher I make the fps, the faster the video plays, meaning the more I have to slow it down and then its still choppy. I'm pretty sure that it captures frames at a really slow rate and then puts them in a video and plays it back at 30fps. Can anyone fix this? Anything that gets a working screen recorder on mac os I will take.

It’s unlikely your loop runs once every 1/30s, since the steps within the loop itself incur relatively significant computational overhead in a single thread. Each frame is only captured after the processing takes place, which is likely exceeding this threshold. You could get closer by farming out the processing steps to another thread but you’d still have to consider that ImageGrab.grab() by itself may take longer than 1/30s dependent on a multitude of factors. On the flip side, if that call takes less than 1/30s, you’d need a mechanism to throttle frame capture to get the right frame rate

Consider using a screen-capture FFmpeg device instead of the custom Python loop of yours.
In cli, run
ffmpeg -devices

and it'll give you a list of devices you have available on your system and you should be able to find ones which can capture screen. For example, on my Windows PC, I get
Devices:
 D. = Demuxing supported
 .E = Muxing supported
 --
 D  dshow           DirectShow capture
 D  gdigrab         GDI API Windows frame grabber
 D  lavfi           Libavfilter virtual input device
  E sdl,sdl2        SDL2 output device
 D  vfwcap          VfW video capture

What's available varies from OS to OS FYI. You can then read up on your options at ffmpeg.org and use the one you picked as the input device for your subprocess call.
